# Debugging and tracing RxJava with lambda, Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, lambda, rx-java

I am working in a project which written entirely using `lambda` expressions, and to make things harder, it mixed with `RxJava`, I included a very simple piece of that code

```
       return tokenExchangeClient.requestToken(identity)
                .doOnError( e -> logError(e,TOKEN_REQUEST_FAILED))
                .map(AccessTokenResponseModel::getAccessToken)
                .flatMap(token -> paymentAdapter.initiatePayment(paymentRequest, token))
                .doOnError(e -> logError(e,PAYMENTS_POST_FAILED))
                .flatMap(InternalToExternal::convertToTransferInitiationResponse);
```

How can I debug and trace this `lambda` with `RxJava` like the old and simple java days ?

Comment: What do you want to debug or what do you want to trace? Like placing a debug point in IntelliJ shall do it. Are you looking forward to something better?

Comment: I place breakpoints at each operator and move from breakpoints to breakpoints. This avoids me from getting into different rxjava classes. I know it's not something clean, but thats how I used to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just place a breakpoint at the beggining of the lambda and run the project in debug mode, then when the debug stop in the breakpoint you can press the "**F8**" key to go step to step in the lambda.

I'll link you the official documentation about breakpoints > https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: Have you tried it yourself with a java program using rxjava? If not, you may wanna see.

Comment: I think it will step into the lambda operators.

Comment: Yes sir, I've tried, in fact, I'm working on a project using rxjava and IntelliJ, this works for me when I need to debug.